# Can we have a franchise tag for The Conjuring universe?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are total 4 main and spin-off films release till date in The Conjuring franchise and there will be more in the future.

So, can we have a tag for The Conjuring franchise in order to get all questions of this franchise under one tag? [the-conjuring](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-conjuring) can be used, but it refers to the first The Conjuring movie.

[This franchise got The Conjuring Universe as an official name.](https://www.myannabellecreation.com/)

Comment: Sure...what do you suggest? [tag:conjurverse]? Ugh! Recall that the tag must be easy to find.

Comment: @Paulie_D We don't have to think that far. [tag:the-conjuring-universe] should be sufficient.

Comment: I could get behind that.

Comment: @Paulie_D There are around 22 questions till now. It'd not require much efforts.

Comment: Did we decide on [tag:blumiverse]? It seems to be attached to the latest question - perhaps a synonym is required?

Comment: @Paulie_D I don't know. I have searched about it, but found nothing. Plus, it's not easy to find.

Comment: @Paulie_D So, we're settled with [tag:the-conjuring-universe]?

Comment: Yeah...it's significantly less confusing that Blumiverse although, as I said, it could be a synonym but that needs a mod.

Comment: @Paulie_D If any term occurs in future, we can ask moderators to synonymize it. Till then, we can work with this tag.

Comment: @Paulie_D Let's start editing.

Comment: I don't feel the need to edit the tag into existing questions.

Comment: @Paulie_D It's just 22 questions.

Comment: But not all of them need it.

Comment: @Paulie_D OK. I have left 8 questions and edited 14
.

Comment: Um, did you do this from the overwhelming support this meta question gathered?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson I know. I did a mistake. But I didn't edit all of them. 14 I guess.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Should I rollback them?

Comment: So what now? Delete the tag again until we have some more consensus? Seems strange, too. I guess it turned out fine for you in the end.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson And consensus? Do we get a lot of meta activity here?

Comment: @AJ yes more then this post for sure which have +1/-1

Comment: @TommyTommy which connections shown in Ouija which make it cannon to Conjuring films ?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson [This franchise got The Conjuring Universe as an official name](https://www.myannabellecreation.com/)(Look at header part). So, is there still need to gather the community consensus here?